# How can i make this function work with other operators

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm doing an exercise, this exercise is about making a simple on screen calculator, the task description specify to make a function add,multiply,subtract,divide that takes two numbers that will be evaluated.. 
but i check some live versions from other people who did the exercise and it accepts more than two numbers so perhaps they use an array.. i tried attempting to make one too but this one doesn't work with other operators like /=,*= and -= .. 
how can i make this work with these operators not just addition..

I'm not on the DOM work yet, i'm still trying to first make this add function work before i move to the HTML part so this is the only code i have right now incase you'll wonder where's the rest.

This one works when adding.

```
function add(arr){
  var ans = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    ans += arr[i];
  }

  return ans;
}
add([100,2000,3000]);
```

But if change to other operators such as -,/,* it only returns 0;
this one is divide

```
 function divide(arr){
      var ans = 0;
      for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        ans /= arr[i];
      }

      return ans; // will return 0
    }
    divide([2000,1000]);
```

Comment: "doesn't work" in what way?  How is this code failing?

Comment: First you should rename the function so it will be generic, and you can use another argument with the array to specify the operation.

Comment: Maybe set `var ans = arr[0]` and then start `i = 1`.

Comment: That's because `0/1000/2000` is `0`.

Comment: sorry for lack of information, i edited it. it returns 0 if tried with other operators such as /.* or - only + evaluates to a valid answer.

Comment: @chsdk sorry i misplaced the two it's [2000,1000]

Comment: Any value times 0 equals 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can just take a function for every operation in an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and then call this function again for each element of the array with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var operators = {
        addition: function (a, b) { return a + b; },
        subtraction: function (a, b) { return a - b; },
        multiplication: function (a, b) { return a * b; },
    };

function calculate(operand, values) {
    return values.reduce(operators[operand]);
}

console.log(calculate('addition', [40, 1, 1]));
console.log(calculate('subtraction', [40, 1, 20]));
console.log(calculate('multiplication', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're starting with `ans = 0` when you should be starting off with the first item in the array. And if you start off with the first item you should start your loop on the second. This should work for all cases but below I have implemented division as an example.

```js
function div(arr){
  var ans = arr[0];
  for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
    ans /= arr[i];
  }
  return ans;
}
let answer = div([100,2000,3000]);

console.log(answer);
console.log(100/2000/3000)
```

Comment: Thanks for this appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your big mistake is that you are always multiplying or dividing by `0` wich will affect athe whole result.

You should initialize the result to the first array element:

```
 function divide(arr){
      var ans = arr[0];
      for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
        ans /= arr[i];
      }

      return ans; // will return 0
    }
    divide([2000,1000]);
```

But I whould recommend using `.reduce()` it will avoid having this problem:

```
     function divide(arr){
          return arr.reduce(function(a, b){
                return a/b;
          });
      }
```

**Demo:**

```js
     function divide(arr){
          return arr.reduce(function(a, b){
                return a/b;
          });
     }
        console.log(divide([2000,1000, 10]));
```

Comment: Your loop shouldn't start at 0 or else you divide arr[0] by arr[0]. Also, you forgot to change the function call from add to divide.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain Yes it was a typo I fixed it, thank you.